# Using Several plugin inputs in the same config file in Logstash

Tags: logstash-configuration

**I'm new to Logstash.** i was able to configure input and output plugins and everything is working as it should.
If i want to configure additional sources and destinations? should i add those plugins in the same config file, what is the best method?

Thanks!